# Can we run objective c on UNIX operating system?

Tags: programming, compiler

How can I run objective c on Unix systems?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get to "run"? (You can't "run" Objective-C code, it needs to be compiled first.)

Comment: I'm presuming you ask because it's mostly connected to Mac programming but Mac OSX is itself Unix. It was created in the 1980s, long before Apple was around.

Comment: @Rob *"in the 1980s, long before Apple was around"* Apple was founded in 1976 (and incorporated in 1977, according to Wikipedia).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - Time flies when you're having fun, eh?

Comment: Apple didn't start using Objective-C until the 1990s when they merged with NeXT.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can find some compilers for Objective-C for UNIX. The only one I can think of for now is [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/).

Keep in mind you won't have access to the Cocoa API that is running on Apple products only. However, [GNUStep](http://www.gnustep.org/) is trying to implement something similar to Cocoa and is written, of course, in Objective-C.

Comment: There is also [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/).